# how do you render displacements in cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, displacement

i was hoping someone could help me figure out why my rendered image doesnt render what the viewport sees. the first image is of the viewport and the second is the actual rendered image. any idea whats wrong?

[image: viewport render]
[image: cycles render]

full screenshot:[image]
i did change a few settings on the material but they really just changed the shape of the crystal spikey things. thats why it looks different in the 3rd image

Comment: Hello :). Please upload a screen of your whole 3D viewport. There might be many reasons, but we don't have enough information in the images provided.

Comment: i did it! thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be the *Suzanne* head, blocking the light. It is hidden in viewport, but appears in render, casting a shadow. Just disable it in renders and you're good to go :).

Click the *filter* button, and show all visibility options.  The *camera icon* disables objects in render. *Click the camera icon to disable in render:*

[image]

Comment: im stupid. i completely forgot about that. i hid it from the camera but its in the exact same spot. thank you for the help!

Comment: Happy to help :). And you ain't stupid, same thing happened to me when i switched to 2.8 :).